# Error: Could not find or load main class NewAssesment.Orenge Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NewAssesment.Orenge

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, classnotfoundexception

This is recent code that i run in my eclipse and i got this exception my previous programme run properly but recent programme are throwing this exception

i have tried to configure the build path but this is not working .i my expecting that code should be run properly

```
package NewAssesment;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Orenge {
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver ();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        System.out.println("i m dipali");
    }

}
```

output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class NewAssesment.Orenge
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NewAssesment.Orenge
```

Comment: It could be an issue with your version of selenium. Maybe it is incompatible with you used java version.

Comment: Clean and compile your workspace. How do you run this? Does your IDE recognize your source folder as a sources root?